# Rails Remove Certain routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, controls

I have a rails app and I have some custom routes. I have a database called Reports. In my routes.rb i have `match '/new' => 'reports#new'` however the problem is that /new goes to the right place, but /reports/new is also still active. Is there a way to "deactivate" the standard /reports/new so that only /new works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're only interested in disabling one action `except` may be more appropriate than `only`. It works in a similar way.

`... :except => :new`

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created

Comment: yeah, when one wants to _remove_ a route, the `except` option is more appropriate (so your answer should be upvoted, too)

Answer (score 5):

Sure, there is. You can use the `only` option as in (for example):

```
resources :reports, :only => [:create, :edit, :update]
```

which defines routes only for the specified actions (run `rake routes` to see all the routes)
(so it doesn't *remove* routes, it just does not generate them)

Edit: Plus, of course, there's also the `except` option (also see @Andy Gaskell's anwers) - which generates all routes except for the given actions, see the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html).